# SQLite Table not saving

Tags: sqlite

I have a query regarding SQLite. I am running it on Mac OS X. I created a table, added, deleted rows,columns values and everything is working fine. But when i close the terminal and exit, and reopen the terminal again, the table that i created previously is no longer there. is thi sthe normal behaviour like session only or am i going wrong somewhere.

Comment: hey, user253987, once someone answered your question "approve it" (click a button below the answer's points). this will give carma to the other users, and show other people who see your question that this is the right answer.

Comment: You should mark the correct answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you connecting to a database by name. If not by default the  sqlite3 engine will create an in-memory database, and that will disappear once you disconnect.

Try starting your session with something like this:

```
sqlite3 my_database.litedb
```

Comment: Hi...Thanks for this info. I did not know that by default the engine creates an in-memory database. That would explain why it is no longer there when i reconnect. But i could not comprehend how to sort this. I am not sure i understand what is meant by connecting to a database by name...Could u slightly elaborate...Thx a billion anyways

Comment: Ah...What a n00B i've been... I confused the table we create as the DB...got it...Now it works fine. I never created a db, just created some tables... Thx a lot again buddy!

Comment: No problem. I make mistakes too before my first coffee.