# Why my tables disappeared suddenly when i'm using SQLIte Manager?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlitemanager

I'm using SQLite Manager for my project but sometimes all my tables disappear suddenly.

So what should I do for this?i'm confused because data in the table gone also.

Please help me..

Comment: You'll have to show us some code so we can help.

Comment: It could be a famous [copy local](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3167395/1997232) thing. You start software, create tables, but on the next start it's again empty, right?

Comment: @IronSlug it's not about the code. I think about setting database in the SQLite Manager but i don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @Sinatr i don't know. i'm open again for several times and then my database empty. All my tables gone.

Comment: @SantiRahayu Woops, my bad. IMO Doug Dawson has it right.

Answer (score 0):

I found two links that might be of use.

[SQLite Table not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698130/sqlite-table-not-saving)

> Are you connecting to a database by name? If not by default the sqlite3 engine will create an in-memory database, and that will disappear once you disconnect.

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/help-with-no-such-table-error-with-sqlite.1141918/

The second link is interesting because if you do reference a db file, but say your path is incorrect, the engine will create an empty file instead of returning an error.

> If the database is opened (and/or created) successfully, then SQLITE_OK is returned.

I hope this helps!

Comment: For reference in the my project, i don't add sqlite3 because it's error. I'm using .db for my database in the SQLite Manager. Which path is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't use SQLite Manager. I thought it was interesting, though, that if SQLite can't find the DB file, it creates a new, empty one. That might explain why the data and the tables are missing.